# Estimating parameters when drawn from known distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, estimation

I'm trying to estimate a model where the data can be partitioned into subsets that each depend on a single parameter value, where the set of these parameters follow a known distribution. Because the data can be partitioned, I can consistently estimate each parameter separately on the relevant partition of the data using MLE. However, it seems like there would be efficiency gains from exploiting my knowledge of the distribution of parameters in the estimation. Is there a way to do this?

To give a concrete example, suppose there are $N$ parameters $\theta=\{\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_N\}$ that are distributed according to the standard normal distribution $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. For each of the $N$ parameters, the data $X_n$ consist of $M_n$ observations drawn from a normal distribution where the mean is given by the associated parameter $\theta_n$ and the standard deviation is $1$, such that $X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta_n,1)$. Ignoring the fact that the parameter values are drawn from a known distribution, the log-likelihood function is given by
$$
\mathcal{l}(\theta,X)=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(-\frac{M_n}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{M_n}(x_{nm}-\theta_n)^2\right),
$$
which can be maximized either by taking the derivative with respect to each parameter to obtain the usual maximum likelihood estimators ($\hat\theta_n=\frac{1}{M_n}\sum_{m=1}^{M_n}x_{nm}$) or maximizing numerically. Is there a way to alter the likelihood function or otherwise change the estimation strategy to make use of the fact that $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to having a prior in Bayesian terminology. Instead of MLE you can find [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimates of the parameters.  Since the posterior probability is proportional to the product of the likelihood and the prior, effectively this just adds $\theta_n^2/2$ terms to your objective function, so you can still easily find the maximum in closed form.

Comment: "Random Effects" is another perspective on this setting.

Comment: From a Bayesian perspective, you need to provide a measure of "good estimation", namely _a loss function_ quantifying the error in estimating $\theta_i$ by an arbitrary estimator $\hat\theta_n$. Minimising the posterior expected loss returns the optimal Bayes estimator (and never the MAP).